# load another UIView from same xib to add as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I have UITableView is Storyboard.
I try to create UITableViewCell in Xib and register it in UITableView as that:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FlipperTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"fliperCell"];
}
```

It work perfectly.

But this cell must have one view inside and flip it to another view when button on first view pressed.

I create another two views in same xib. 
File's owner is FliperTableViewCell class. Class of first view is FliperTableViewCell.
[image]

But now a can't figure out how to add second view (UIView) as subview in first view (UITableViewCell), which loaded by table view.
I try to get second view from loadNibNamed:, but it became infinite cycle.

```
@implementation FlipperTableViewCell
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is another way to get second view from same xib and add it as subview when first view loaded?

Comment: Have you tried creating multiple views and hooking them up in the xib? It should create and connect them for you when it's loaded.

Comment: I edited my question and added xib image. When tableView will create instance of FlipTableViewCell class, in this instance I want get access for second view. My problem that I doesn't know how to get this second view from instance of first one.

Comment: Put "face" and "View" *inside* flipperCell, and hide them.  Then, at runtime, unhide the one you want to see in response to the button press.  Doing it this way, everything is already hooked up in the xib, so you don't have to do anything to load it.

Comment: seems like this is only way to do that. I was trying to split cell to several views for convenience in creating views. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was solved when I replace

```
[self.tableview registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FlipperTableViewCell"];
```

to

```
[self.tableview registerClass:[FlipperTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FlipperTableViewCell"];
```

then remove first view from xib and rewrite FlipperTableViewCell to initiate in code

```
#import "FlipperTableViewCell.h"

@interface TableViewCell ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *firstView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *secondView;
@end

@implementation FlipperTableViewCell
-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil];
        self.firstView = nibObjects[0];
        self.secondView = nibObjects[1];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.firstView];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}

// this is for test changing views
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (self.contentView.subviews[0] == self.firstView){
        [self.firstView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.secondView];
    }
    else{
        [self.secondView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.firstView];
    }
}

@end
```